# Is there a design pattern to remove the need to check for flags?

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented-design, refactoring

I'm going to save some string payload in the database. I have two global configurations:

- encryption
- compression

These can be enabled or disabled using the configuration in a way that either only one of them is enabled, both are enabled or both are disabled.

My current implementation is this:

```
if (encryptionEnable && !compressEnable) {
    encrypt(data);
} else if (!encryptionEnable && compressEnable) {
    compress(data);
} else if (encryptionEnable && compressEnable) {
    encrypt(compress(data));
} else {
  data;
}
```

I'm thinking about the Decorator pattern. Is it the right choice, or is there perhaps a better alternative?

Comment: What's wrong with what you currently have?  Are the requirements likely to change for this functionality?  IE, are there likely to be new `if` statements?

Comment: No, I'm looking at any other solution to improve the code.

Comment: You're going about this backwards. You don't find a pattern then write code to fit the pattern. You write the code to fit your requirements, then optionally use a pattern to _describe_ your code.

Comment: I reopened this for right now as I see the questions are inherently different and may be confusing to readers.  If you would like to discuss this then please open a question in Meta and we can discuss if that was the right choice.

Comment: note if you believe that your question is indeed a duplicate of [this one](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/137999/31260), then as an asker you have an option to "override" recent reopen and singlehandedly close it as such. I did that to some of my own questions and it works like a charm. [Here is how I did it, 3 easy steps](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250974/165773) - the only difference with my "instructions" is that since you have less than 3K rep, you will have to go through [flag dialog](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Accms.png) to get to "duplicate" option

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: There's some truth in what you say, but it's perfectly reasonable to ask if there's a better way to structure one's code, and it's perfectly reasonable to invoke a design pattern to describe a proposed better structure. (Still, I agree that it's a bit of an XY problem to ask for a design *pattern* when what you want is a *design*, that may or may not strictly follow any well-known pattern.) Also, it's legitimate for "patterns" to affect your code slightly, in that if you're using a well-known pattern, it often makes sense to name your components accordingly.

Comment: @ruakh: Yeah, granted.

Comment: Say what?  Design patterns is that they offer proven solutions to known design problems.  Looking for patterns that might solve your problem (before you code) is exactly how they are supposed to be used.  I have no idea what the 46 ppl are doing that upvoted that comment.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When designing code, you alaways have two options.

1. just get it done, in which case pretty much any solution will work for you
2. be pedantic and design a solution which exploits the quirks of the language an its ideology (OO languages in this case - the use of polymorphism as a mean to provide the decision)

I am not going to focus on the first of the two, because there is really nothing to be said. If you just wanted to get it to work, you could leave the code as it is.

But what would happen, if you chose to do it the pedantic way and actually solved the problem with design patterns, in the way you wanted it do?

#### You could be looking at the following process:

When designing OO code, most of the `if`s which are in a code do not have to be there. Naturally, if you want to compare two scalar types, such as `int`s or `float`s, you are likely to have an `if`, but if you want to change procedures based on configuration, you can use [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism) to achieve what you want, move the decisions (the `if`s) from your business logic to a place, where objects are instantiated - to [factories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

As of now, your process can go through 4 separate paths:

1. `data` is neither encrypted nor compressed (call nothing, return `data`)
2. `data` is compressed (call `compress(data)` and return it)
3. `data` is encrypted (call `encrypt(data)` and return it)
4. `data` is compressed and encrypted (call `encrypt(compress(data))` and return it)

Just by looking at the 4 paths, you find a problem.

You have one process which calls 3 (theoretically 4, if you count not calling anything as one) different methods that manipulate the data and then returns it. **The methods have different names**, different so called public API (the way through which the methods communicate their behaviour).

Using the [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) pattern, we can solve the name colision (we can unite the public API) that has occured. Simply said, adapter helps two incompatible interfaces work together. Also, adapter works by defining a new adapter interface, which classes trying to unite their API implement.

> *This is not a concrete language. It is a generic approach, the **any** keyword is there to represent it may be of any type, in a language like C# you can replace it with generics (`<T>`).*

I am going to assume, that right now you can have two classes responsible for compression and encryption.

```
class Compression
{
    Compress(data : any) : any { ... }
}

class Encryption
{
    Encrypt(data : any) : any { ... }
}
```

In an enterprise world, even these specific classes are very likely to be replaced by interfaces, such as the `class` keyword would be replaced with `interface` (should you be dealing with languages like C#, Java and/or PHP) or the `class` keyword would stay, but the `Compress` and `Encrypt` methods would be defined as a [pure virtual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function), should you code in C++.

To make an adapter, we define a common interface.

```
interface DataProcessing
{
    Process(data : any) : any;
}
```

Then we have to provide implementations of the interface to make it useful.

```
// when neither encryption nor compression is enabled
class DoNothingAdapter : DataProcessing
{
    public Process(data : any) : any
    {
        return data;
    }
}

// when only compression is enabled
class CompressionAdapter : DataProcessing
{
    private compression : Compression;

    public Process(data : any) : any
    {
        return this.compression.Compress(data);
    }
}

// when only encryption is enabled
class EncryptionAdapter : DataProcessing
{
    private encryption : Encryption;

    public Process(data : any) : any
    {
        return this.encryption.Encrypt(data);
    }
}

// when both, compression and encryption are enabled
class CompressionEncryptionAdapter : DataProcessing
{
    private compression : Compression;
    private encryption : Encryption;

    public Process(data : any) : any
    {
        return this.encryption.Encrypt(
            this.compression.Compress(data)
        );
    }
}
```

By doing this, you end up with 4 classes, each doing something completely different, but each of them providing the same public API. The `Process` method.

In your business logic, where you deal with the none/encryption/compression/both decision, you will design your object to make it depend on the `DataProcessing` interface we designed before.

```
class DataService
{
    private dataProcessing : DataProcessing;

    public DataService(dataProcessing : DataProcessing)
    {
        this.dataProcessing = dataProcessing;
    }
}
```

The process itself could then be as simple as this:

```
public ComplicatedProcess(data : any) : any
{
    data = this.dataProcessing.Process(data);

    // ... perhaps work with the data

    return data;
}
```

No more conditionals. The class `DataService` has no idea what will really be done with the data when it is passed to the `dataProcessing` member, and it does not really care about it, it is not its responsibility.

Ideally, you would have unit tests testing the 4 adapter classes you created to make sure they work, you make your test pass. And if they pass, you can be pretty sure they will work no matter where you call them in your code.

#### So doing it this way I will never have `if`s in my code anymore?

No. You are less likely to have conditionals in your business logic, but they still have to be somewhere. The place is your factories.

And this is good. You separate the concerns of creation and actually using the code. If you make your factories reliable (in Java you could even go as far as using something like the [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice) framework by Google), in your business logic you are not worried about chosing the right class to be injected. Because you know your factories work and will deliver what is asked.

#### Is it necessary to have all these classes, interfaces, etc.?

This brings us back to the begining.

In OOP, if you choose the path to use polymorphism, really want to use design patterns, want to exploit the features of the language and/or want to follow the everything is an object ideology, then it is. And even then, this example does not even show all the factories you are going to need and if you were to refactor the `Compression` and `Encryption` classes and make them interfaces instead, you have to include their implementations as well.

In the end you end up with hundreds of little classes and interfaces, focused on very specific things. Which is not necessarily bad, but might not be the best solution for you if all you want is to do something as simple as adding two numbers.

If you want to get it done and quickly, you can grab [Ixrec's solution](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/306315/193669), who at least managed to eliminate the `else if` and `else` blocks, which, in my opinion, are even a tad worse than a plain `if`.

> <sub>Take into consideration this is **my** way of making good OO
>   design. Coding to interfaces rather than implementations, this is how
>   I have done it for the past few years and it is the approach I am the
>   most comfortable with.</sub>
>
> <sub>I personally like the if-less programming more and would much
>   more appreciate the longer solution over the 5 lines of code. It is
>   the way I am used to designing code and am very comfortable reading
>   it.</sub>

---

**Update 2:** There has been a wild discussion about the first version of my solution. Discussion mostly caused by me, for which I apologize.

I decided to edit the answer in a way that it is one of the ways to look at the solution but not the only one. I also removed the decorator part, where I meant facade instead, which I in the end decided to leave out completely, because an adapter is a facade variation.

Comment: I didn't downvote but the rationale might be the ridiculous amount of new classes/interfaces to do something the original code did in 8 lines (and the other answer did in 5). In my opinion the only thing it accomplishes is increasing the learning curve for the code.

Comment: In C#, they're called generics.  Templates in C++ are quite a different animal, even though they look similar.

Comment: @Maurycy What OP asked was to try to find a solution to his problem using common design patterns, if such solution exist. Is my solution longer than his or Ixrec's code? It is. I do admit that. Does my solution solve his problem using design patterns and thus answers his question and also effectively removing all the necessary ifs from the process? It does. Ixrec's does not.

Comment: There are a number of posts on meta.stackoverflow.com that discuss at length whether to provide an answer that's in the OP's best interest, or answer the OP's literal question directly.  Your answer clearly falls in the latter category.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So you believe writing crappy code going against SOLID principles, thus, among other things, making testing more difficult and your code less reliable (because it is hard to test and hence tests may be flaky), is the way to go?

Comment: I believe that writing code that is *clear, reliable, **concise,** performant and maintainable* is the way to go.  If I had a dollar for every time someone cited SOLID or quoted a software pattern without clearly articulating their goals and their rationale, I'd be a rich man.

Comment: @DavidPacker: writing code adhering to SOLID principles doesn't automatically make it better, easier to test, or more reliable. Writing code that doesn't adhere to it isn't automatically crappy. Everything has trade-offs and sometimes SOLID is sensible, other times it is now.

Comment: @RobertHarvey My code meets all the criteria, does it not? Unlike OP's and Ixrec's, which have problem with maintainability and if you take into consideration that `if`s are difficult to read, also the conciseness.

Comment: @whatsisname You do have a point, it brings to mind the Active record / Data mapper issue systems have (as to active record, although an anti pattern, might be more suitable for your system if it is a small one). Still, if you want a data mapper specifically, why would you settle with active record instead?

Comment: I think I have two issues I see here. First is that the `Compression` and `Encryption` interfaces seem totally superfluous. I'm not sure if you are suggesting that they are somehow necessary to the decoration process, or merely implying that they represent extracted concepts. The second issue is that making a class like `CompressionEncryptionDecorator` leads to the same kind of combinatorial explosion as the OP's conditionals. I'm also not seeing the decorator pattern clearly enough in the code suggested.

Comment: @DavidPacker Sure, I didn't say you haven't answered the OP's question but I wanted to point out that, at least to me and possibly to the downvoter(s), it's like killing a fly with a nuclear warhead.

Comment: I agree with the spirit of the answer here and upvoted it.  He is advocating for Decorator pattern to describe the class then encapsulating the conditional logic within an Abstract Factory or in a Service or Business Logic layer as one would in Transaction Script pattern.  *This is a sound approach* verbosity be damned.  It promotes separation of concerns and encourages all unit testable code to be within either a Service class or a Factory.

Comment: (cont...) with that being said, the code example above I do question if it is the best example of Decorator.  In Java I like annotations better for decorating a class.

Comment: @Maurycy I don't understand the witch hunt against verbosity.  It ranks pretty low on my priority list for good code.  I find it easier to get a complete grasp of all aspects of software as written when it is verbose than something that was done in a clever ad-hoc way with no general guiding design or principles.

Comment: The debate on SOLID vs. simple is kinda missing the point: this code is neither, and it also does not use the decorator pattern.  Code is not automatically SOLID just because it uses a bunch of interfaces.  Dependency injection of a DataProcessing interface is kinda nice; everything else is superfluous.  SOLID is an architecture-level concern aimed at handling change well.  OP gave no information about his architecture nor how he expects his code to change, so we can't really even discuss SOLID in an answer.

Comment: @maple_shaft: Quite simply, if nearly all the code is boilerplate, you have to parse and discard it all to get to the parts which actually *do* anything. The verbosity is killing performance, productivity, and maintainability. Always keep in mind YAGNI and KISS.

Comment: @maple_shaft The decorator pattern was an awful example and I meant a variation of the facade pattern instead. I apologize for my behaviour, which was unacceptable. Having to work on the NYE sucks, I was tired. I do not inted to remove the answer, but I edited it in a way to make sure it acts as a one of the possibilites. I am happy with the solution and would gladly accept it, if an interviewee presented it before me.

Comment: @Deduplicator In a compiled language, performance is really not the issue. It is all compiled to machine code anyway. And we know the premature optimization is evil. Productivity and maintainability is in my opinion a matter of what you are used to. I, personally, am used to the pure OO design, find it incredibly easy to read and with good logging mechanism and well defined exceptions also incredibly easy to debug and maintain.

Comment: @maple_shaft As other have already explained better than I it's not a witch hunt. Verbosity hurts readability as much as the opposite. Of the two I'd probably rather work on overarchitectured code than in CoffeeScript with all commas, brackets, braces and parenths dropped but why chose the lesser evil if you can chose the right thing?

Comment: Also as other people have mentioned not everything has to be "proper". It's a very important skill to know when 8 ugly lines is better than 8 pretty classes. And "what if we need to expand this later?" is not the best argument for me either - refactor it then. Keep it simple and don't do things you will probably never need.

Comment: @DavidPacker My actual problem has three encryptions and two compressing methods. I think this is very suitable for my question.

Comment: I had upvoted you because I do think the decorator pattern does in principle solve this problem. However upon careful reading, I noticed the code examples don't apply this pattern correctly. A decorator should take an instance of the object it decorates and delegate most of it's implementation to it. That requires less code and avoids the exponential explosion caused by things like CompressionEncryptionAdapter.

Comment: @DavidPacker: Performance is only one of my three points, and the weakest at that. Anyway, you cannot ignore even that one unless the compilation from source reduces all your boilerplate to nothing, and there's not a JIT step or such which will be burdened with it. Also, purity for purity's sake is a dearly beloved anti-pattern.

Answer (score 118):

The only problem I see with your current code is the risk of combinatorial explosion as you add more settings, which can be easily be mitigated by structuring the code more like this:

```
if(compressEnable){
  data = compress(data);
}
if(encryptionEnable) {
  data = encrypt(data);
}
return data;
```

<sub>I'm not aware of any "design pattern" or "idiom" that this could be considered an example of.</sub>

Comment: I think you missed my additional condition 'encrypt(compress(data));' I want to data compress and encrypt too.

Comment: @DamithGanegoda Nope, if you read my code carefully you'll see it does exactly the same thing in that case. That's why there's no `else` between my two if statements, and why I'm assigning to `data` each time. If both flags are true, then compress() gets executed, then encrypt() gets executed on the result of compress(), just like you want.

Comment: @lxrec Yeah I got you'r point

Comment: Your solution violates the [Open/Closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle), Ixrec.

Comment: @DavidPacker Technically, so does every if statement in every programming language. I went for simplicity, since this looked like a problem where a very simple answer was appropriate. Your solution is valid too, but personally I'd save it for when I have a lot more than two boolean flags to worry about.

Comment: I would not bother if OP had not asked for a design pattern to help him solve the problem. On top of that, with the decorator he suggested he was already on the right track, interested in the right OO approach, and you showed him the wrong way - with flags and `if`s... That saddens me. Just because it makes more sense to do it the wrong way now does not mean you should not try to do it correctly.

Comment: @DavidPacker: correct is not defined by how well the code adheres to some guideline by some author about some programming ideology. Correct is "does the code do what it's supposed to do and was it implemented in a reasonable amount of time". If it makes sense to do it the "wrong way", then the wrong way is the right way because time is money.

Comment: @whatsisname If you were in OP's position and wanted to find a solution using design patterns and recieved the one of Ixrec's noting that: *I'm not aware of any "design pattern" or "idiom" that this could be considered an example of,* even though it is a clear example of the decorator/adapter collaboration, which can be implemented in 5 minutes (that is not really a long time), would you be happy with the provided short example instead of the one you seeked?

Comment: @DavidPacker: If I was in the OP's position, and asked that question, Lightness Race in Orbit's comment is what I really need. "Finding a solution using design patterns" is already starting from the wrong foot.

Comment: @whatsisname You completely avoided the answer.

Comment: This is definitely the clean way to do this.

Comment: @DavidPacker Actually if you read the question more closely, it doesn't insist on a pattern. It states, *"I'm thinking about the Decorator pattern. Is it the right choice, or is there perhaps a better alternative?"*. You addressed the first sentence in my quote, but not the second. Other people took the approach that no, it is not the right choice. You can't then claim that only yours answers the question.

Comment: @JonBentley Sadly, those are my own words, the way how I reworded the questions  to meet the standards of this site instead of being a cry fo help. I will  take the blame for that. The original question said: *I'm thinking about the Decorator pattern.Please help me out find good design pattern to handle this.*

Comment: "I'm not aware of any "design pattern" or "idiom" that this could be considered an example of." -- Not a pattern or idiom, really, but it seems like a straightforward application of the DRY principe to me, although at a much smaller scale than usual. The logic of mapping the compressionEnable flag to the compress function was originally in two places, it's in one now. Ditto for encryption.

Comment: This style can be adapted easily in to a _Chain of Responsibility_ pattern. The pattern helps avoid "combinatorial explosion". An excellent example of CoR (which uses encryption and compression as possible handlers) is the implementation of [ChannelPipeline in the Netty project](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html).

Comment: @hvd Another similar principle would be [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle), which fits this case nicely. If  one wants to name the pattern just for the sake of naming it something just call it "Anti-Arrowhead pattern" and be done with it.

Comment: I should not be getting this many upvotes for writing two if statements and a return.

Comment: There's a reason this answer is getting 10 times as many votes as the accepted answer: Sometimes the "quick and dirty" solution is the right one, and the pedantic solution is ridiculous.

Answer (score 12):

I guess your question is looking not for practicality, in which case lxrec's answer is the correct one, but to learn about design patterns.

Obviously the [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) is an overkill for such a trivial problem as the one you propose but for the sake of illustration here it goes:

```
public interface Command {
    public String transform(String s);
}

public class CompressCommand implements Command {
    @Override
    public String transform(String s) {
        String compressedString=null;
        //Compression code here
        return compressedString;
    }
}

public class EncryptCommand implements Command {
    @Override
    public String transform(String s) {
        String EncrytedString=null;
        // Encryption code goes here
        return null;
    }

}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Command> commands = new ArrayList<Command>();
        commands.add(new CompressCommand());
        commands.add(new EncryptCommand()); 
        String myString="Test String";
        for (Command c: commands){
            myString = c.transform(myString);
        }
        // now myString can be stored in the database
    }
}
```

As you see putting the commands/transformation in a list allows for ther to be executed sequentially. Obviously it will execute both, or only one of them dependind og what you put in the list without if conditions.

Obviously the conditionals will end up in some kind of factory that puts together the command list.

**EDIT for @texacre's comment:**

There are many ways of avoiding the if conditions in the creational part of the solution, **let's take for example a desktop GUI app**. You can have checkboxes for the compress and encrypt options. In the `on clic` event of those checkboxes you instantiate the corresponding command and add it to the list, or remove from the list if you are deselecting the option.

Comment: Unless you can provide an example of "some kind of factory that puts together the command list" without code that essentially looks like Ixrec's answer then IMO this doesn't answer the question. This provides a better way of implementing the compress and encrypt functions, but not how to avoid the flags.

Comment: @thexacre I added an example.

Comment: So in your checkbox event listener you have "if checkbox.ticked then add command"? It seems to me like you're just shuffling the flag if statements around...

Comment: @thexacre No, one listener for each checkbox. In the click event just `commands.add(new EncryptCommand());`  or `commands.add(new CompressCommand());` respectively.

Comment: What about handling unchecking the box? In just about every language / UI toolkit I've encountered you'll still need to check the state of the checkbox in the event listener. I agree this is a better pattern, but it doesn't avoid needing basically if flag do something somewhere.

Answer (score 7):

I think "design patterns" are unneccesarily geared towards "oo patterns" and completely avoiding much simpler ideas. What we're talking about here is a (simple) data pipeline.

I would try to do it in clojure. Any other language where functions are first-class is probably ok as well. Maybe I could a C# example later on, but it's not as nice.
My way of solving this would be the following steps with some explanations for non-clojurians:

**1. Represent a set of transformations.**

```
(def transformations { :encrypt  (fn [data] ... ) 
                       :compress (fn [data] ... )})
```

This is a map, i.e. a lookup table/dictionary/whatever, from keywords to functions. Another example (keywords to strings):

```
(def employees { :A1 "Alice" 
                 :X9 "Bob"})

(employees :A1) ; => "Alice"
(:A1 employees) ; => "Alice"
```

So, writing `(transformations :encrypt)` or `(:encrypt transformations)` would return the encrypt function. (`(fn [data] ... )` is just a lambda function.)

**2. Get the options as a sequence of keywords:**

```
(defn do-processing [options data] ;function definition
  ...)

(do-processing [:encrypt :compress] data) ;call to function
```

**3. Filter all transformations using the supplied options.**

```
(let [ transformations-to-run (map transformations options)] ... )
```

Example:

```
(map employees [:A1]) ; => ["Alice"]
(map employees [:A1 :X9]) ; => ["Alice", "Bob"]
```

**4. Combine functions into one:**

```
(apply comp transformations-to-run)
```

Example:

```
(comp f g h) ;=> f(g(h()))
(apply comp [f g h]) ;=> f(g(h()))
```

**5. And then together:**

```
(def transformations { :encrypt  (fn [data] ... ) 
                       :compress (fn [data] ... )})

(defn do-processing [options data]
  (let [transformations-to-run (map transformations options)
        selected-transformations (apply comp transformations-to-run)] 
    (selected-transformations data)))

(do-processing [:encrypt :compress])
```

The ONLY changes if we want to add a new function, say "debug-print", is the following:

```
(def transformations { :encrypt  (fn [data] ... ) 
                       :compress (fn [data] ... )
                       :debug-print (fn [data] ...) }) ;<--- here to add as option

(defn do-processing [options data]
  (let [transformations-to-run (map transformations options)
        selected-transformations (apply comp transformations-to-run)] 
    (selected-transformations data)))

(do-processing [:encrypt :compress :debug-print]) ;<-- here to use it
(do-processing [:compress :debug-print]) ;or like this
(do-processing [:encrypt]) ;or like this
```

Comment: How is funcs populated to only include the functions which need to be applied without essentially using a series of if statements in one way or another?

Comment: The row `funcs-to-run-here (map options funcs)` is doing the filtering, thus choosing a set of functions to apply. Maybe I should update the answer and go into a bit more detail.

Answer (score 5):

[ Essentially, my answer is a follow-on to the [answer by @Ixrec above](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/306315/134647). ]

An important question: is the number of distinct combinations that you need to cover is going to grow?  You are better aware of your subject domain.  This is your judgement to make.
Can the number of variants possibly grow?  Well, that's not inconceivable. For example, you may need to accommodate more different encryption algorithms.

If you anticipate that the number of distinct combinations is going to grow, then [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) can help you.  It's designed to encapsulate algorithms and provide an interchangeable interface to the calling code.  You would still have a small amount of logic when you create (instantiate) the appropriate strategy for each particular string.

[You have commented above](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/306314/is-there-a-design-pattern-to-remove-the-need-to-check-for-flags#comment642137_306314) that you don't expect the requirements to change.  If you don't expect that the number of variants would grow (or if you can defer this refactoring), then keep the logic the way it is.  Currently, you have a small and manageable amount of logic.  (Maybe put a note to self in the comments about a possible refactoring to a Strategy pattern.)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this in scala would be:

```
val handleCompression: AnyRef => AnyRef = data => if (compressEnable) compress(data) else data
val handleEncryption: AnyRef => AnyRef = data => if (encryptionEnable) encrypt(data) else data
val handleData = handleCompression andThen handleEncryption
handleData(data)
```

Using decorator pattern to achieve the above goals (separation of individual processing logic and how they wire together) would be too verbose.

Wherein you would require a design pattern to achieve these design goals in an OO programming paradigm, functional language offers native support by using functions as first class citizens (line 1 and 2 in the code) and functional composition (line 3)

Comment: Why is this better (or worse) than the OP's approach?  And/or what do you think about the OP's idea to use a decorator pattern?

Comment: this code snippet is better and is explicit about ordering (compression before encryption); avoids unwanted interfaces